# Analytics: Consolidation across devices and applications

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I use different **Google Analytics** properties to track separately:

- Blog
- Website
- iOS app
- Android App

I am looking for a way to combine all these trackers to see a global view of my analytics.

The first ideas is to have an additional new tracker for all platforms. Does it not seems to be a best practice...
I also use a common MixPanel tracker to tracks users across platforms but MixPanel does not offers the demographics view, which is one the most important things for me.

Would love to get some recommandation for this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Google Analytics does just that and more. From merging to consolidating based on  user view permissions**

**Analytics accounts**
An Analytics account is a way to name and organize how you track one or more properties (e.g. websites, mobile apps, point-of-sale devices) using Analytics. Each Analytics user has access to at least one account, either one they created themselves, or one that they were given access to by someone else. In each Analytics account, at least one property (such as a website) is being tracked. As shown above, an Analytics account can be used to track a single property, or it can track many distinct ones, depending upon the requirements of its use.

A given web property should only be tracked in one Analytics account. Tracking a single web property in different Analytics accounts is not currently recommended.

You do not need to sign in separately for each Analytics account that you have access to. In the above example, Liz signs in to Analytics with her Google Accounts email ID (liz@gmail.com); she can then select any of the Analytics accounts that she has access to.

**Analytics accounts organization**
If you are using Analytics to track a single website, account organization is simple: you will have one account for your website. For setting up Analytics accounts to manage multiple websites, keep in mind the following:

**Each Analytics account can have up to 50 properties and each property can have up to 25 views**. Contact your support representative if you need more properties or views.

**You can grant users view permissions (Manage Users, Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze) on:**

1. An Analytics account
2. A property under an Analytics account
3. A view under a property

With that in mind, consider the following common ways that an Analytics account might be used:

**Track all properties owned by a single person or organization.**
For example, you might have an Analytics account named My Personal Account for your personal web properties. In this account, you would track your personal website and your blog, which are separate properties. In this case, you use one tracking code snippet on your website pages, and use a different one for your blog.

You might also set up different Analytics accounts for different groups or stakeholders. For example, if you administer Analytics tracking for two companies, you would set up a separate Analytics account for the websites owned by each company. Since you might want to provide administrative access to individuals in each company, you would not want to expose sensitive reporting data between companies, so it makes sense to track the websites from different companies in separate accounts.

**Track a single property.**
By default, an Analytics account is designed to track at least one property. However, this is also a good way to set up Analytics if the site/app you are tracking is large and has a number of contributors interested in viewing reports across that property. In this way, the collection of views within an account all correspond to the same property.

**For instance, suppose you are the administrator for example.com, which has a number of sub-directories.** If each department wants to track their section of the site/app independently from others, you can create distinct reporting views within the account that include only data from certain sections. In this scenario, you install the tracking code for the site/app once, and any difference in reporting views are handled by the views and their filters.

You can learn a lot more here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1102152?hl=en

and here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

**For Querying data from multiple views (profiles)**

Through the Google Analytics web interface you can only see reports and visualization data from a single view (profile) at a time. With this add-on you can run reports on any number of views (profiles) and use the generated data in whatever way you like. For example, if you have a view that tracks your iOS traffic and a separate view to track your Android traffic, you could use this add-on to run reports on both views and easily compare the results side by side, in the same spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As they are separate properties, I don't think this is possible within GA.

What I would do, it combine the CSV files for all of the different properties into one location. (Excel etc). 
You could even set up automatic emails to send you this report from all of the properties to save you some of the leg work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, yes you can do this. Generally, it seems easiest with another UA number, then editing the script a bit to run a subdomain for the tracker. I laid out how to do it here in another question on Pro Webmasters if you are interested: [Google Analytics tracking on multi domain environment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90682/google-analytics-tracking-on-multi-domain-environment/90959#90959)

That should get you closer, assuming there is no special circumstances in the mobile apps or their tracking methods (ie, offline use).